# checkpoint file not detected in colab after reconnecting

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

`!pwd` gives */content/gdrive/My Drive/slt/sign_sample_model* 
`!ls` gives *best.ckpt    gls   references.dev.gls  train.log
config.yaml  gls.vocab  tensorboard     validations.txt*

````
checkpoint = torch.load('best.ckpt')``` gives error  <br/>
 **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'best.ckpt'**
````

Comment: Does this work `checkpoint = torch.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/slt/sign_sample_model/best.ckpt')`?

Comment: no , this also did not work